# Proof for vector space structure on $V/U $

Tags: proof-verification, quotient-spaces

**Task:**

> Assume $K$ is a field, $V$ is a vector space over $K$ and $U \subset V$ is a vector subspace. Let $V/U$ be the set of the equivalence classes regarding the equivalence relation defined by $U$ ($u \sim v$ iff $u - v \in U$) on $V$ and let $q: V \rightarrow V/U$, $v \rightarrow [v]$ be the canonical projection.
>
> Then there is a unique vector space structure on $V/U$ such that $q$ is a linear map.

**Proof:**

Since the canonical projection should be linear, the addition must be given by $[v] + [w] = [v + w]$ and the scalar multiplication by $a[v] =[av]$.

Especially there can only be one vector space structure with the required properties, and we have to show that we have well defined operations on $V/U$ that are independently from the representative. This means that for $[v] = [v']$ and $[w] = [w']$ we have to show that $[v + w] = [v' + w']$

> Well, now he is showing why this is true for the addition and the scalar multiplication. He then finishes the proof with:

Since the conjunction is well defined and the map is surjective, it follows that we have indeed a vector space structure and that the map is linear.

**Questions:**

1. I don't understand why he wants to show that $[v] + [w] = [v + w]$. What does this even mean? Sure, we somehow sum up two equivalence classes, but how can I image doing that?
2. Furthermore, it feels like he proves this statement by showing that $[v] = [v']$ and $[w] = [w'] \Rightarrow [v + w] = [v' + w']$. But why?
3. And last but not least, why does it follow that the map is linear? Just because wie map into a vector space, this map doesn't have to be linear, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be preferable to work with an example which is easier to get a feeling that abstract symbolic operations.

Take the vector space $V$ to be vectors in a plane. A subspace $U$ to be some line passing through origin (the zero vector) in the plane. (There are no axes, just origin).  The cosets $V/U$ are simply the collection of all the lines of the plane parallel to $U$.

Note that these lines cover the whole plane and are disjoint pairwise. To add two cosets $L, L'$ pick one vector from each of these lines. Add these two vectors and find the unique line  $L''$ that contains the sum of those two vectors. We declare $L+L'$ to be $L''$: to say this operation is well-defined you must check that different choices of vectors from the same lines  even if gives different vector as sum, will be in the same line $L''$.

The linear map $V$ to $V/U$ is given a vector find the line parallel to $U$ containing the given vector (Euclid's fifth postulate). Check it is linear.

Comment: Thank you very much! But how does it come in hand that the map is surjective? How does this tell me anything about the vector space structure or that the map is linear?

Comment: Given a line parallel to $U$, pick a vector $w$ on that line. What will our map $V\to V/W$ associate to this $w$?. Its is the line we started with. So surjectivity follows. Given two vectors we have associated lines. To check linearity use parallelogram law of vector addition (draw pictures).